# Closing an Ajax Modal Popup using a command button from the popup form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have two aspx pages. On the first page, I have hard-coded the `ModalPopupExtender` and named it `ID="mp1"` as shown below:

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server"
    PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="HiddenControl1"
    BackgroundCssClass="Background" >
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" style = "display:none" >
    <iframe style=" width: 400px; height: 300px;" id="irm1" src="Form2.aspx" runat="server">
    </iframe>
    <br/>
</asp:Panel>
```

I didn't specify the `CancelControlID` because I want the popup to close using the button inside the `src="Form2.aspx"`. I tried calling the `mp1` control in the `Form2.aspx.vb` but I keep getting a `NullReferenceException` error using this code:

```
 Protected Sub cmdCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCancel.Click
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to quit?", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Warning") = vbYes Then
        Dim parentForm As New Upload_File 'Upload_File is the class name of the First Form
        parentForm.mp1.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you omit parentForm out of the equation? Doing just "mp1.Hide()"? The code as it stands right now you declare a new Upload_File and then tells it to Hide the mp1 in that new Upload_File, but I don't Think that'll fly since you only constructed the object in the line Before in the code.

Comment: My bad. Didn't read all the way through. But if you try referencing the second form, like "form2.mp1.Hide()" directly, without first seting a constructor on a new instance of the object?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that the mp1 ModalPopupExtender is in the first aspx page which is the Upload_File.aspx. What I am trying to do is to close the popup using the command button cmdCancel located in Form2 which is the source form of the popup window. Anyway, if I try referencing mp1 directly to the page like Upload_File.mp1.Hide(), it returns this error: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Comment: Have a look here, it might help. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=155

Comment: Tried it and still haven't had any luck. Anyway, instead of using an Ajax ModularPopupExtender, I just decided using javascript code window.open and I think it's pretty much did the job. But hopefully, I'll find out sooner or later how to access the control from another form. Thanks